# Checking checkboxes does not appear to effect underlying HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of which one column contains checkboxes that look like:

```
<tbody>

    <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1"></td>
```

the table is initially generated with all check boxes not checked. but when I look at the underlying html with firebug after checking a box , there is no change.

How can I programmatically evaluate whether a box is checked or not?

Comment: [`.prop('checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, use the `.checked` property:

```
if (element.checked) {
    ...
}
```

Changing input elements from the UI doesn't change them in the DOM.